# Lucene TermsFilter speeds up first query, slows down subsequent ones

Tags: performance, filter, lucene

I'm using Lucene 3.6.1

I initially had a query that for a given input of "true love" would create a query like this:

```
+(+content:true +content:love) 
+(title:"true love"^3.0 ((title:true title:love)^2.0) 
(subTitle:true subTitle:love)) 
title_starts_with:true love*^3.0 
+showToPublic:y
```

Query times were :

- 1rst query after application stars (no warm-up): 250-300 ms
- subsequent query: 35-40 ms

Reading up on [Lucene's Search Speed Tips page](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed) I've found they recommend using filters when possible:

*Consider using filters. It can be much more efficient to restrict results to a part of the index using a cached bit set filter rather than using a query clause. This is especially true for restrictions that match a great number of documents of a large index. Filters are typically used to restrict the results to a category but could in many cases be used to replace any query clause. One difference between using a Query and a Filter is that the Query has an impact on the score while a Filter does not.*

So I've removed the  `+showToPublic:y` part of my query, and added a [TermsFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/TermsFilter.html) like so:

```
TermsFilter showToPublicFilter =  new TermsFilter();            
showToPublicFilter.addTerm(new Term("showToPublic","y"));
indexSearcher.search(booleanQuery, showToPublicFilter, collector);
```

What I've noticed is that now the first query is substantially faster but subsequent queries are a lot slower than before:

- 1rst query after application stars (no warm-up): 200-220 ms
- subsequent query: 190-200 ms

I find this strange, since the TermsFilter's JavaDoc sais it's ideal to my current situation:

*Constructs a filter for docs matching any of the terms added to this class. Unlike a RangeFilter this can be used for filtering on multiple terms that are not necessarily in a sequence. An example might be a collection of primary keys from a database query result or perhaps a choice of "category" labels picked by the end user. As a filter, this is much faster than the equivalent query (a BooleanQuery with many "should" TermQueries)*

I've also tried using [FieldValueFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldValueFilter.html) (since my "showToPublic" field has either "y" or no value):

```
FieldValueFilter showToPublicFilter =  new FieldValueFilter("showToPublic", false);  
indexSearcher.search(booleanQuery, showToPublicFilter, collector);
```

but with this I get no results at all (sure is faster, though).

So my question is:

- is this normal behavior, i.e. filters are not guaranteed to always be faster than equivalent boolean queries?
- is there some other filter I should use (I've looked through them all, to me it seems TermsFilter and/or FieldValueFilter are the only ones applicable to this scenario)?
- why doesn't FieldValueFilter work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using [CachingWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html) which Wraps another filter's result and caches it. Reuse it.

The underlying Filter.getDocIdSet() is called each time a FilteredQuery is used in search, so it is recommended to use a caching filter if the query is to be used repeatedly and the filter results don’t change.

If you use the caching mechanism, you might find performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing (a TermsFilter placed in a CachingWrapperFilter for the "+showToPublic:y" part). Now the whole query is roughly twice as fast.